# python 'and' operator and 'else' block

Tags: python, operators

I wrote a code that generates a random number from 0 to 100.
After using it in an if statement, I print the number after the else block.

```
import random

while True:
    n = random.randint(0,100)
    if (n < 100 and n > 0):
        pass
    else:
        print(n)
```

As I know it shouldn't print out any number, because the number can't be 'not' smaller than 100 and 'not' larger than 0 at the same time. My experience is that it doesn't check both conditions at the `else` block.

Using 'or' instead of 'and', there were no printed numbers.

My goal is to only let numbers between 0 and 100 enter the if block and no numbers should be printed out in the else block (with print(n)).

Edit:
Referring to the @C_Z_ comment: In python, using `and` in the statemnt if one condition becomes false it enters the else block.

Comment: You will only enter the `if` block if BOTH conditions evaluate to true - that is what the `and` operator does. For an `and` statement, python will evaluate both conditions. If either is false, the entire `and` statement evaluates to `false` and you enter the `else` block.

Comment: In this case, I have to use `elif` block so it will check both conditions. I thought it enters the else block only if both conditions are false because I used 'and'.

Comment: If you only want to enter the else block if both conditions are `false`, then you want to use the `or` operator instead of the `and` operator, like you mentioned. The `or` operator will evaluate to true if either or both of the conditions are true, and will evaluate to false if both conditions are false (which sounds like what you want)

Comment: If I use `or` operand it will let the number 100 entered in the if block. My case is to let only numbers between 0 and 100 enter the if block.

Comment: Then you need to use `<=` and `>=` to exclude those values

Comment: *"because the number can't be 'not' smaller than 100 and 'not' larger than 0"* — [Yes it can.](https://www.aroundtheworldin80jobs.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/obama-yes-we-can.jpg) `0` is not larger than 0 and `100` is not smaller than 100.

Comment: You can rephrase your condition as `if 0 < n < 100`. Well, [`randint` generates a number such that `0 <= n <= 100`.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) So, they're not the same.

Answer (score 1):

`random.randint(0,100)` will generate numbers between 0 and 100 (including both 0 and 100), so the test case you're using will sometimes fail.

What if you used inclusive bounds:

```
    if (n <= 100 and n >= 0):
```

instead? Does that work like you'd expect?

Answer (score 1):

That's because using `and` one of the 2 codition is false

- number 100: `n < 100` False `n > 0` True
- number 0: `n < 100` True `n > 0` False

So you need to add `<=` and `>=` operator in order to make BOTH condition true :

```
import random

while True:
    n = random.randint(0,100)
    if n <= 100 and n >= 0:
        pass
    else:
        print(n)
```

Answer (score -1):

Referring to the [@C_Z_ comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67873620/python-and-operator-and-else-block/67875324#comment119969058_67873620):

> For an and statement, python will evaluate both conditions. If either is false, the entire and statement evaluates to false and you enter the else block.

**Using `or` instead of `and`**:

If using `or` in the if statement, it only enters the `else` block if BOTH conditions are **false**.
But then it will enter the `if` block, if at least one condition is **true**.
Using a second if with the unused condition.**`if n < max`**

```py
import random

min = 0
max = 100
while True:
    n = random.randint(min, max)
    if (n > min or n < max):
        if n < max:
            print(n)
    else:
        print(n)
```

In this case, because I used 'and', I have to check the opposite of the conditions with `elif`.

**Using the `elif` block.**

```py
import random

min = 0
max = 100
while True:
    n = random.randint(min, max)
    if n < max and n > min:
        pass
    elif not n < max and not n > min:
        print(n)
```

`elif not n < max and not n > min` is the opposite of `if n < max and n > min`.

Comment: I think you're confusing yourself with double negative conditional thinking…